# C# Timer only starts at first "if"

Tags: c#, if-statement, timer

I'm making a game and want to show texts at various scores.
But at the moment the timer only works (the text only shows) at the first if (so if the score equals 100)
I need some help because it needs to work with 200, 300, 400, ... -1000 too.

Here's the code:

```
void startTimer()
{  
    if (score == 100)
    {   
        timerWIN.Start();  
    } 
    else if (score == 200)   
    {    
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 300)  
    {  
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 400)  
    {    
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 500)  
    {    
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 600)  
    {    
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 700)  
    {    
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 900)  
    {    
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 1000)  
    {    
        timer1000.Start();  
    } 
}


private void timerWIN_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{   
    if (timerTick == 1)   
    {
        lblWin1.Visible = true;
        lblWin2.Visible = true;   
    }   
    else if (timerTick == 15)   
    {
        lblWin1.Visible = false;
        lblWin2.Visible = false;
        timerWIN.Stop();   
    }

    timerTick++; 
}

private void timer1000_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{   
    if (timerTick == 1)   
    {
        lblWin1.Text = "500 points!";
        lblWin2.Text = "You're doing great.";
        lblWin1.Visible = true;
        lblWin2.Visible = true;   
    }   
    else if (timerTick == 15)   
    {
        lblWin1.Visible = false;
        lblWin2.Visible = false;
        lblWin1.Text = "Yeah that's it.";
        lblWin2.Text = "Keep feeding me baby.";
        timer1000.Stop();   
    }

     timerTick++; 
}
```

As requested, here's how I give score: (everytime I collide, I get score)

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  snakeScoreLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(score);

  if (down) { snake.moveDown(); }
  if (up) {snake.moveUp(); }
  if (right) {snake.moveRight(); }
  if (left) {snake.moveLeft(); }

  for (int i = 0; i < snake.SnakeRec.Length; i++)
  {
    if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))
    {
      score += points;
      snake.growSnake();
      food.foodLocation(randFood);
      startTimer();
    }

  }


  collission();

  this.Invalidate();

}
```

Comment: How do you invoke startTimer?

Comment: Please format your own code in future...

Comment: You should replace your mega `if` statement with a `switch` statement or even a much simplified `if` statement. Much cleaner. Also properly formatting your code may have enabled you to spot the error yourself.

Comment: have you heard about or `||` statement? you almost always start `timerWIN`.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a separate timer per score or is it really supposed to be `timerWIN` up to 900 then `timer1000`? I think your code could definitely be simplified to using 1 timer if all it's doing is updating the score.

Comment: How does the value of `points` get determined before it is added to `score`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are increasing the `score` as per your requirement. From the code given above score is updating nowhere.

**Suggestion:** make your code concise by using the code snippet below:

```
void startTimer()
{  
    if (score >= 100 && score <= 900 && score % 100 == 0)
    {   
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }  
    else if (score == 1000)  
    {    
        timer1000.Start();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question at first, you could simplify your code by using a switch statement it might help you find the error in your logic because from the code provided it's difficult to see where exactly you are going wrong.

```
switch (score)
{
    case 100:
    case 200:
    case 300:
    case 400:
    case 500:
    case 600:
    case 700:
    case 800:
    case 900:
        timerWIN.Start();
        break;
    case 1000:
        timer1000.Start();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Based on your update, I assume `points` is a fixed value at 100?

Comment: no its a fixed value of 10 points, but only at every 100 points you get the labels to show

Comment: Ah ok, so have you checked whether the correct score is coming into the `startTimer` method?

Answer (score 0):

Show the code fragment, where `score` is being modified.

---

You should change your `startTimer` method as following:

```
void startTimer()
{
    if(score == 1000)
    {
        timer1000.Start();  
    }
    else if(score % 100 == 0 && score < 1000)
    {
        timerWIN.Start();  
    }
}
```

And,

within `timer1000_Tick` method, shouldn't you stop `timer1000` in place of `timerWIN`.

```
timer1000.Stop();
```

Comment: I get the feeling it's supposed to be a different timer per score e.g. timer100/timer200 etc. I imagine the `timerWIN` is just a copy/paste job

Comment: no. values 100, 200, ... 900 all have timerWIN
Value 1000 should have timer1000
Fixed the timer1000.stop

Comment: Your else if will incorrectly be execute for a value of 0 also.